# I can't connect to xRDP by enter 127.0.0.1, but I can connect to it by enter "localhost"

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

I was installed GUI of Kali Linux on WSL. Now when I tried connect it through Remote Desktop Connection, I can’t connect to it by type **127.0.0.1:3390**, but I can connect by type **localhost:3390**. `127.0.0.1` is localhost IP, but why not it work here?

Also I can’t connect to it by using default listening port of xRDP which is 3389, I have to change the port number. In internet I found that I have to change the port 3389 to 3390. But I check that I can change the default port to any port (for example 1323). So, why I have to change the default port and why it should be 3390?

Even graphical view of the Kali Linux desktop environment is not like other graphical view, it seems like older.

Comment: The connection probably uses address `::1` for localhost.

Comment: @JohanMyréen but `::1` is not a localhost IP, so how can it used for connection?

Comment: It's WSL, not Linux, so all bets are off.

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 address for localhost. If RDP is refusing connections on `127.0.0.1`, then `::1` is tried. What does `host localhost` print?